# Laravel, appending an attribute to a returned json appends the entire object

Tags: laravel, object, attributes, append

I have 2 tables `Customer`(Parent) and `jobCode`(Child) with one to many relationships

I want to retrieve a child record but with one extra field from the parent (`customerGuid`) as well. My code:

```
$jobCodes=JobCode::all();

foreach ($jobCodes as $jobCode) {
    $jobCode['customerGuid']=$jobCode->customer->guid;

    // I also tried  $jobCode->setAttribute('customerGuid',$jobCode->customer->guid);
}

return $jobCodes;
```

I was expecting just the parent's `guid` field to be appended to each `jobCode` object and returned. However the ENTIRE `customer` parent object is returned!

```
[{
    "id": 137,
    "customerId": 1,
    "jobCode": "Journeyman Plumber",
    "jobDescription": "Journeyman Plumber",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": "2017-01-27 12:20:27",
    "guid": "28f35e94-e483-11e6-98e9-e0db55883624",
    "customerGuid": "8d48931d-dc61-11e6-8927-e0db55883624",
    "customer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ACME",
        "address1": "",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "San Jose",
        "zip": "",
        "phone": "",
        "fax": "",
        "email": "",
        "guid": "8d48931d-dc61-11e6-8927-e0db55883624",
        "stateName": "California",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": "2017-01-20 07:10:59"
    }
}, {
    "id": 138,
    "customerId": 1,
    "jobCode": "JRP PreFab",
    "jobDescription": "JRP",
     ......,
```

Comment: Hi, can you please share the result of dd(JobCode::all()); ?

Comment: I guess you mean dd(jobCodes::all()). It is the same result. Includes the entire customer record instead of just the one field customerGuid
-----------
{"id":137,"customerId":1,"jobCode":"Journeyman Plumber","jobDescription":"Journeyman Plumber","created_at":null,"updated_at":"2017-01-27 12:20:27","guid":"28f35e94-e483-11e6-98e9-e0db55883624","customerGuid":"8d48931d-dc61-11e6-8927-e0db55883624",
    "customer":{"id":1,"name":"ACME","address1":"","address2":"","city":"Milpitas","zip":"","phone":"","fax":"","email":"","guid":"8d48931d-dc61-11e6-8927-e0db55883624","stateName":"Cali...

Comment: So that means that is not because of your setAttribute, you wrote it correct, the issue is in your relational methods of JobCodes Model. Can you share it please?

Comment: class JobCode extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'jobCodes';
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer','customerId','id'); 
    }

}

Answer (score 0):

Its because your return statement returns `$jobCodes;` which is the entire table you retrieve here: `$jobCodes=JobCode::all();`

try putting this inside your loop
`echo '$jobCode'` to see what is the output every time it loops

Comment: I get the same result. The parent customer object is nested inside the jobCode object. My code only asks for one field from the customer table: customerGuid

Answer (score 0):

Reaching for the relationship `customer` on `$jobCode` you automatically lazy load the relationship object, which is stored in `$jobCode->customer` attribute.

Try this instead just returning the collection:

```
// return $jobCodes;

return $jobCodes->map(function($jobCode){
          $jobCode = $jobCode->toArray();
          unset($jobCode['customer']);
          return $jobCode;
       });
```

Comment: Great..that worked. I did this.
foreach ($jobCodes as $jobCode) {
  //add an extra attribute
  $jobCode['customerGuid']=$jobCode->customer->guid;
 unset($jobCode['customer']);
}
return $jobCodes;